# New keyword in JS

Tags: javascript

I have been looking at the new keyword in JS.
I understand this means that the this keyword is now created in the object.
One thing I don't understand is how inside the testNew function baz is undefined.

```
function testNew()
{
    this.baz = "baz";
    console.log(this.bar + " "  + baz);
    console.log(this.baz);
}

var bar = "bar";
var baz = new testNew();
console.log(baz);
```

As this would now be attached to the new object would this.baz and baz not be the same reference?

Comment: Change this.bar + " "  + baz to this.bar + " "  + this.baz

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at this line,

```
var baz = new testNew();
```

What's happening here is:

1. `baz` variable is created with value undefined
2. `testNew` function is called, `this` inside of it is a new object, but `baz` is still undefined
3. `testNew` finishes and returns the newly created object which is then assigned to `baz`

Comment: Are you sure that baz is initialized with "undefined" or does it simply not exists at this point until the function is done?

Comment: According to [Ecmascript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-variable-statement):  _var statement declares variables that are scoped to the running execution context’s VariableEnvironment. Var variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated and are initialized to undefined when created._

Comment: Good to know, thank you very much for the reference!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function testNew()
{
    this.baz = "baz";
    console.log("this.bar + \" \"  + baz: ", this.bar + " " + baz); // this fails
    console.log("this.baz: ", this.baz);
}

var bar = "bar";
var baz = new testNew();
console.log("baz: ", baz);
```

You are trying to access `this.bar`, which does not exist inside your testNew() function. You defined `bar` on a global namespace and can call it using `bar`.
Also `baz` is not defined at the moment you try to call it since you are referencing the global `baz` which you are currently initializing with your testNew() function

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
One thing I am not quite getting. 
In the test new function, I set baz using this.baz.
When I try and get that later, why is not using the scope of the function to find it?

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing local variable with this code ... " " + baz, there is no local variable 'baz' is defined.

It should be

```
this.bar + " " + this.baz
                 ^^^
```

Comment: this.bar is still undefined

Comment: because bar variable isn't inside the newly created object, bar variable is defined in global context

Comment: I know - see my answer. But you suggested to change `baz` to `this.baz` but ignored `this.bar`. If you suggest to "fix" one value I'd assume `this.bar` should also be fixed.

Comment: His question is about baz variable not bar variable

Comment: Fair point, though it still feels incomplete I agree with you about his question and your answer.